# Embedding a 3-dim cv::Mat in a 4-dim cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have to embed a 3-dimensional `cv::Mat` into a 4-dimensional one.

Some context

**Given:** I have some code performing a depthwise convolution, i.e. I have a 3-dim input matrix {channels, w_in, h_in} and a 3-dim 3-by3 kernel {channels, 3, 3} to produce a 3-dim output {channels, w_out, h_out}. Depthwise convolution now means that the first slice of the kernel is applied on the first slice of the input to produce the first slice of the output, and so on.

**What I need:** I want to rebuild this type of convolution using a standard convolution which needs a 4-dim kernel. In python (pytorch) I could do something like:

```py
kernel4d = torch.tensor((), dtype=torch.float32)
kernel4d = kernel4d.new_zeros((channels, channels, 3, 3))
for i in range(channels):
    kernel4d[i, i, :, :] = kernel3d[i, :, :]
```

How can I re-write this code efficiently in C++ using `cv::Mat`?

---

**EDIT**

```
int size3d[] = {3, 5, 5};
cv::Mat kernel3d = cv::Mat(3, size3d, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(0));

int size4d[] = {3, 3, 5, 5};
cv::Mat kernel4d = cv::Mat(4, size4d, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(1));

// Try 1
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    kernel4d.at<float>(i, i) = kernel3d.at<float>(i);
}
// Result: Sets only single values at (i, i, 0, 0)

// Try 2
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++){
            kernel4d.at<float>(i, i, k, l) = kernel3d.at<float>(i, k, l);
        }
    }
}
// Result: at does not exept 4 indexes
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did it fail?

Comment: Well, I do not have that much experience with OpenCV C++. I have a 4-dim `cv::Mat` but I'm not sure how to put the data in it. I found the `at` method in the docs but from my understanding, I can only set single values with it (and a lot of loops). But this does not work as expected - and I'm not sure whether this is the best implementation.

Comment: Please don't *describe* what you did...**show** what you did. I.e. a [mcve]. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Ok, I've added two things I've tried.